# Convolution of two heaviside functions

Tags: analysis

how can i find convolution of two heaviside functions centered at  1/2 and -1/2.
I have tried to find the corresponding integral, but i stack due the centers are different.

Answer (score 6):

Let $H(t)$ be the Heaviside function.  Note that $H(\tau-1/2)\neq 0$ only when $\tau>1/2$ and that $H(t-\tau+1/2) \neq 0$ only when $t-\tau > -1/2 \implies \tau < t + 1/2$.  These only occur simultaneously for $t\geq 0$

So, the convolution will be $0$ when $t<0$.  For $t>0$, we compute
$$
\begin{align}
H(t-1/2) * H(t+1/2) &=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(\tau-1/2)H(t-\tau+1/2)\,d\tau
\\ &=
\int_{1/2}^{t+1/2} H(\tau-1/2)H(t-\tau+1/2)\,d\tau
\\ &=
\int_{1/2}^{t+1/2} 1\,d\tau = t
\end{align}
$$
That is, we have
$$
H(t-1/2) * H(t+1/2) = 
\begin{cases}
t & t \geq 0\\
0 & t < 0
\end{cases} = t\,H(t)
$$